# ArgumentError when using enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

I got this error when accessing 'MyModel'

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0) from /Users/.../.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/enum.rb:131:in `block (4 levels) in enum'
```

when I use enum on my model

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base       
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  enum transaction_type: { send: "send", reset: "reset", top_up: "top_up" }
end
```

which has never happened before. I don't think I did anything different than usual when setting it up.

Comment: use array as `enum`

Comment: @uzaif that won't work in my case

Answer (score 1):

Your error appeared because you used the value "send" as enum value here. ["send"](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send) is a method that is available on all ruby objects. Hence instead of accessing the enum, rails accidently tries to use the "send" method and this is the reason why you get the "wrong number of arguments" error. Use something else like "send_out".

Answer (score 0):

When using enums and passing a hash, the value should be an intgers only

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base       
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  enum transaction_type: { send: 0, reset: 1, top_up: 2 }
end
```

Alternatively, you can use arrays

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base       
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  enum transaction_type: [ :send, :reset, :top_up]
end
```

**Note:** once a value is added to the enum array, its position in the array must be maintained, and new values should only be added to the end of the array. If you don't want this, the explicit hash syntax above should be used.

Comment: are you sure its integer only? My user model use enum like this ( enum role: { user: "user", admin: "admin"  } ) which works just fine

Comment: That depends on the data type of your `transaction_type` column is it a string or an int?

Comment: the data type is string